# Earliness: the quality of being early

Tags: diction

Which words help convey the concept of *being early*?

*Prompt* is not exactly what I want, as it means "on time" in the context I am considering.  If spring (the season) was a spirit and arrived two weeks early this year, and was content in doing so, how could I describe the idea that spring doesn't mind its *_*__ness (quality of being early)?

Comment: That's probably not a valid answer, just a suggestion : changing slightly the idea from early to quick would open more possibilities: quickness hastiness swiftness ?

Comment: @Alain: that's an interesting suggestion!  I like the way you think.  Perhaps I could say "vernal celerity."  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Timeliness or prematureness are probably too vague and spurious respectively.

Could I suggest removing the constraint that it is __ness and suggest "spring doesn't mind being an early bird," which might even have some pleasant connotations if spring is what is actually being written about.

Comment: as @JPmiaou posted, the usual noun form of premature is *prematurity*.

Comment: @Martha indeed and thus spurious ;)

Comment: The early bird gets its name from being early from Winter (migrating back, before the Spring), I think, so although I like your suggestion, it hints to circularity in definition.

Answer (score 2):

I like *earliness* best, but if you don't mind being a little on the fringe, you could try [*prepunctuality*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/prepunctuality).

Comment: Thus far my favorite suggestion =]

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with *earliness*?

I suppose there's also *forwardness*, though that doesn't quite fit your example. Neither do *untimeliness* or *prematurity*.

Answer (score 0):

**Premature** is a good alternative, though I'm not sure it lends itself to the noun form you desire. Consider the following phrasings:

> Spring doesn't mind being premature.

or

> Spring doesn't mind arriving prematurely.

EDIT: If you like the noun form, you can always use **earliness** as well.